# Write permissions for IBM Containers Volume as non-root user

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Using IBM Containers to run the [following Docker image](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile), the image uses a non-root user to run the application process. Application data is stored in `/data`, which is mounted to an external volume to persist this data outside of the container.

Starting this container on IBM Bluemix, the `/data` directory is now owned by root. This means the non-root application process cannot write files to this directory and crashes.

The Dockerfile for the image creates the `/data` directory and changes the ownership to the correct uid. However, the directory permissions are being picked up from the external volume host.

Other than changing the application process user back to root (which is a security issue), is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

You can map a host directory of (where you have required permissions) to /data in the container.

docker run -v /myhome/mydir:/data

Comment: I'm using the IBM containers volume service rather than binding a local host directory on IBM Bluemix. This is not relevant to my scenario.